# Attach ELB instance to "Application Load Balancer"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

## Questions

1. How to attach Elastic Beanstalk instance to **Application Load Balancer** (ALB)?
2. Why is ALB ignored and AWS creates a new Classic LB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Elastic Beanstalk [Configuring an Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-applicationloadbalancer.html) documentation says:

> You can set the load balancer type only during environment creation using the EB CLI, the Elastic Beanstalk APIs, or using .ebextensions like the one in the example `.ebextensions/application-load-balancer.config`; **the console does not support this functionality**.